# .NET Thank you/confirmation page best practice

Tags: asp.net

Whats the best practice for implementing a confirmation page in .Net?

I've used `response.redirect("Thankyou.aspx")` a lot in the past I've also used something like this for hiding form controls and outputting a message:

```
outResult.Attributes.Remove("style")
outResult.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;")
outEntry.Attributes.Remove("style")
outEntry.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;")
```

For the above you have to consider post backs that may occur if the user click refresh though.

Does anybody have a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a clean nice page like "ThankYou.aspx" just like you suggested and redirect the user there.

Comment: +1. With a Thankyou page you can also track ConversionRates with Google Analytics

Comment: +1 Cintronas, I just didnt know that - "ConversionRates with Google Analytics " as I never used GA. I was just stessing on a clean way to display the page. I just dont like postbacks for this. Thanks for the input. I will give GA a try. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best practice is not to use a post-back, but instead a normal form action, bring you to a new page.  That page processes the form, and displays the Thank you.